# libstatistics_collector: Unknown CMake command "rosidl_get_typesupport_target" (galactic)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I am trying to build ROS2 from source following the [galactic link](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#get-ros-2-code). While building, I am getting the below error,

```
Starting >>> shape_msgs
--- stderr: libstatistics_collector
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:100 (rosidl_get_typesupport_target):
  Unknown CMake command "rosidl_get_typesupport_target".


make: *** [Makefile:1130: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
---
Failed   <<< libstatistics_collector [5.11s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< shape_msgs [1.76s]
Aborted  <<< rclpy [2.80s]
Aborted  <<< map_msgs [4.19s]

Summary: 176 packages finished [1min 34s]
  1 package failed: libstatistics_collector
  3 packages aborted: map_msgs rclpy shape_msgs
  1 package had stderr output: libstatistics_collector
  150 packages not processed
```

I tried to comment it in "src/ros-tooling/libstatistics_collector/CMakeLists.txt" file, but it leads to some other failure. Need some help here.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383979/libstatistics_collector:-unknown-cmake-command-%22rosidl_get_typesupport_target%22-(galactic)/) by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably the same cause as is fixed by [ros2/ros2#1166](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/pull/1166).

Try changing the active branch for `ros-tooling/libstatistics_collector` to `galactic`.

It's set to `master` [here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/blob/1af04b49329d43c54c63bcf1a9302f9462ec1263/ros2.repos#L70-L73), but that isn't correct any more since [ros-tooling/libstatistics_collector#116](https://github.com/ros-tooling/libstatistics_collector/pull/116).

> I tried to comment it in "src/ros-tooling/libstatistics_collector/CMakeLists.txt" file, but it leads to some other failure.

yes, don't do that.

That function call is there for a reason.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on 2021-08-07**:
Thanks a lot for the solution. It fixed the build error. :)

**Comment by [mnokka](https://answers.ros.org/users/87249/mnokka/) on 2021-10-14**:
Thank you! I had similar build error; used ROS2 Foxy, but ROS2 tutorial's branch was rolling, when corrected the branch as suggested (foxy-devel in my case) this  "rosidl_get_typesupport_target" build error disappeared.